# How can i grayout a DataGrid?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am working on flex, i simply need to grayout dataGrid. but could not find any direct control for it. Pls help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to disable your `DataGrid` using:

```
myDG.enabled = false;
```

?

As far as your question isn't any clear I can suggest another thing to use `mx.printing.PrintDataGrid` (more details [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/printing/PrintDataGrid.html)).

Comment: Setting enable false only makes it non-editable. but i need to grayout (change the color to gray). i tried disabledColor too, but doesn't work.

Comment: Color of what? What theme do you use? What Flex version?

Comment: I want to change color of Grid rows. I am not using any theme.

Comment: Try to use `myDG.setStyle("themeColor", 0x999999)` or `<mx:DataGrid themeColor="0x999999" />`

Comment: Or even better: `myDG.setStyle("themeColor", "haloSilver")` or `<mx:DataGrid themeColor="haloSilver" />`

Comment: No, doesn't work. how can i give a string as themeColor?? it don't think it will accept.

Comment: Did you tried `themeColor="haloSilver"` in MXML or in ActionScript? I suppose in ActionScript.

Comment: it worked, no compilation error but its not giving the required output.

Comment: You should just copy my code. This usage `myDG.setStyle("themeColor", "haloSilver")` is for ActionScript. It can't be `themeColor="haloSilver"`. And this code `<mx:DataGrid themeColor="haloSilver" />` is for MXML. Don't be confused.

Comment: So roll over and selection colors on your data grid are still blue?

Comment: I suppose [this topic](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/02/17/setting-the-roll-over-color-and-selection-color-in-a-flex-datagrid-control/) can help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this to differentiate datagrid rows by different colors: you can also use more than 2 color parameters.

```
 <mx:DataGrid alternatingItemColors="[0xfffffff, 0xe4e4e4]" >
...
...
</mx:DataGrid>
```